# IF(A2>A3, 1, 0) Excel formula in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a column with zeros and ones based on values from 1st column.
If the value of upper cell is bigger, then write 1, else 0.
Example code would look like this:

```
df = pd.Dataframe({'col1': [1, 2, 1, 3, 0]})
df['col2'] =  ...python version of excel formula IF(A2>A3, 1, 0)...
```

expected output:

[image]

I have tried:

```
while True:
    for index, rows in df.iterrows():
        df['col1'] = np.where(df['col1'] > df['col1'][index+1], 1, 0)
```

but this is very slow and gives wrong results.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].shift().lt(df['col1']).astype(int)
```

Comment: Elegant solution, exactly what I've been looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Update. After check got that this doesn't match what excel shows in reality. Posted the solution I came up with below. But your answer helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final solution I came up with:

```
df['col2] = (df['col1'<df['col1'].shift()).astype(int).shift(periods=-1).fillna(0)
```